# Split array data before send to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date, split

`print_r($time_and_text[1]);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06:00 &nbsp; Lorem ipsum
    [1] => 17:35 &nbsp; dolor sit amet
)
```

and `print_r($id[1]);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => tt1821597
    [1] => tt2258858
)
```

now, I want to send this to MySQL. To have something like this:
[image: example]

First time when I use MySQL, but I guees this code is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE today
(
    id varchar(255),
    time varchar(255),
    text varchar(255)
)
INSERT INTO today VALUES ('tt1821597', '06:00', 'Lorem ipsum')
INSERT INTO today VALUES ('tt2258858', '17:35', 'dolor sit amet')
```

How it's possible to do this from PHP?

- split `$time_and_text` in `$time` and `$text`;
- send array to MySQL;
- and if it's possible, to replace *today* with date (ex. 31.04.2014).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the array $time__and_text[1]

```
$limit = count($time_and_text[1]) - 1;
for ($index=0; $index<=$limit; $index++){
    $time = substr($time_and_text[1][$index], 0, 5);
    $text = substr($time_and_text[1][$index], 12);

    $query = "INSERT INTO today VALUES ('{$id[1][$index]}', '{$time}', '{$text}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

}
```

I have assumed that $con is the handle which is used to connect to the database.

Comment: But today is the name of the table...??

Comment: This is only possible if you have a field / column for that in the database table.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys of your array always are aligned, you can use this to lik both arrays on a row with the follow code:

```
For($i=0, $i<count($id), $i++) {
    $parts = explode(" &nbsp; ", $time_and_text[$i]);

    $query = "insert into today values ('$id[$i]', '$parts[0]', '$parts[1]')"
}
```

in this loop you can breakout the text with explode to have all the information you need.

edit: added the explode function.

Comment: He wants to break down time and text

Comment: Correct, but I assume that the basic explode function is know.

Comment: Added the explode function, just to be sure and complete.

Comment: You forgot the quotes in your query. Please correct

Answer (score 1):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06:00 &nbsp; Lorem ipsum
    [1] => 17:35 &nbsp; dolor sit amet
)
```

Lets call the above array `$A`. And lets call

```
Array
(
    [0] => tt1821597
    [1] => tt2258858
)
```

as `$B`.

Now, create a `foreach` loop.

```
$count=0;

   $connection= new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
   foreach($A as $a){
   $parts = explode(" &nbsp; ", $a[$count],2);
   $connection->query( "INSERT INTO today VALUES ($B[$count], $parts[0], $parts[1])" );
   $count++;
   }
```

Comment: What's up with that INSERT statement just hanging out?

Comment: Thanks, Is that Ok now?

Comment: Almost - I would use mysqli_query, since mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Well, it can be anything. It can be PDO. Or even something else. It can be what the OP wants. That's the reason I just said INSERT INTO. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Sure, and I understood that you meant "fill this in", but a comment letting the OP know what you mean ensures understanding. You're assuming that the OP will just understand, but to quote you from 47 minutes ago, "You cant assume."

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Split it up by looping through with foreach, build up an array and do a single INSERT.

```
<?php

$insert_array = array();

foreach($time_and_text[1] as $tat_key=>$tat_value)
{
    list($tat_time, $tat_text) = explode(' &nbsp; ', $tat_value);
    $insert_array[] = "('".$id[1][$tat_key]."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $tat_time)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $tat_text)."')";
}

if (count($insert_array) > 0)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO today(`id`, `time`, `text`) VALUES(".implode("),(", $insert_array).")";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
}

?>
```